# Java, unexpected output

Tags: java

I just started to learn Java, using the MIT OCW. The first program I wrote is just a very small calculation but it printed something unexpected. 
So this is my code:

```
public class test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        int s = 120;
        int g = 12;
        double fraction = g/s;
        System.out.println ("Fraction: " + fraction);
       } 
   }
```

I expected this output:

```
Fraction: 0.1
```

But I got this output:

```
Fraction: 0.0
```

I would be very thankful if someone could explain me this output.

Comment: You performed integer division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your vars to be `double` rather than `int` and you will get a better result from division:

```
    double s = 120.0;
    double g = 12.0;
```

In general, remember that in a typed language like **Java**, type matters. `int` will not magically give you a `non-int`, or `double`, result. That's why there are two different types...

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Should I use double instead of int in general or is it important only in this very case?

Comment: "In general"?  No.  You should understand how integer division works, how ints differ from floating point numbers, and choose the right one for each situation.